# Issue with libudev library

Tags: linux, makefile, arm, cross-compiling, udev

I am getting the following *libudev* undefined reference errors while cross compiling to arm.

```
 build_arm/lib//libCoreUtils.so: undefined reference to `udev_monitor_unref'
 build_arm/lib//libCoreUtils.so: undefined reference to `udev_enumerate_scan_devices'
 build_arm/lib//libCoreUtils.so: undefined reference to `udev_new'
 build_arm/lib//libCoreUtils.so: undefined reference to `udev_list_entry_get_name'
...
```

I am using `-ludev` but also getting same error.
Can any anyone help me?

Comment: You will have two 'libudev.so' on the build machine.  One is your host *libudev.so* and the other should be the target.  The header files used to cross compile and the target shared library used to link must match.  Can you demonstrate that you have this correct?

Comment: Checked, I have included header files of target correctly. I tried by giving -ludev, direct path for libudev.so which is redirecting to libudev.so.1.6.2. but still i am getting same error.

Comment: Well, you could have an incorrect command line (compile DEFINES for PC but need DEFINES for ARM, which [pkg-config](https://people.freedesktop.org/~dbn/pkg-config-guide.html) can solve or you are not linking with the library you believe.  You can use `strace` with the file access to double check which library files the tools are accessing.

Comment: Was any progress made here? I am having what I believe is a related error (I am getting the same error in the same context as [this user](https://www.reddit.com/r/sdl/comments/8wrzqe/sdl2_img_init_problem/). Same problem with system SDL2 as built/installed from source.) I have located 'libudev.so': two symlinks to one fully-qualified shared library, `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1.6.9`; no .a/.la or I'd try that. Like @sathish, I linked `-ludev` and gave the direct path. I reinstalled `udev`/`libudev-dev` for good measure. `pkg-config` claims only `-ludev` should be necessary.